# multiple MySQL queries in php not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code for a search algorithm requesting data from a MySQL table.

```
function checkValue($value){
    if($value == 'undefined'){
        $value = '%%';
        return $value;
    }else{
        $value = '%'. $value .'%';
        return $value;
    }
}

$source = $_GET['origin'];
$data = array();


if($source == 'search'){

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where gender = '". $_GET['gender'] ."' and product_name like '". checkValue($_GET['name']) ."' and product_brand like '". checkValue($_GET['brand']) ."' and price > ". $_GET['minPrice'] ." and price < ". $_GET['maxPrice'] );

    $sel = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $sel[] = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where product_no = '". $row['product_no'] ."' and category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat']) ."' or category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat1']) ."' or category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat2']) ."' ");
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)){
        if($row['sale'] == 'true'){
            $data[] = array("name"=>$row['product_name'],"brand"=>$row['product_brand'],"price"=>$row['price'], "img_url"=>$row['img'], "href"=>$row['href'], "sale"=>$row['sale'], "pre_price"=>$row['pre_price'], "post_price"=>$row['post_price'],  "percentage_discount"=>$row['percentage_discount'] );
        }else{
            $data[] = array("name"=>$row['product_name'],"brand"=>$row['product_brand'],"price"=>$row['price'], "img_url"=>$row['img'], "href"=>$row['href'], "sale"=>$row['sale'], "pre_price"=>$row['price'], "post_price"=>$row['price'],  "percentage_discount"=>0);
        }
    }

}
```

This code was working fine previously, without the second command. I've tried applying both these query's in the same query although this invalidates my results. The database is configured and the connection is fine. 
I get an internal server error in console, although this is not a syntax error as all the other query's in the file work fine.

I'm new to php although when I've had a similar problem in python 3 using mysql-connector I've used a buffered cursor, is there an equivalent in php?

Comment: `$sel[]` I think this should be prob change this to `$sel` make this as variable. NOTE: Your query is open to sql injection

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: An Internal Server Error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber i'm aware that is not a very comprehensive error message, I'll check the server logs now.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) expects an `Resource` from a db query however you passed in an `array` of resources.

To keep your code just assign the query into variable `$result2` that will keep the pointer to the query result and then you can walk it using `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where gender = '". $_GET['gender'] ."' and product_name like '". checkValue($_GET['name']) ."' and product_brand like '". checkValue($_GET['brand']) ."' and price > ". $_GET['minPrice'] ." and price < ". $_GET['maxPrice'] );

    $sel = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $result2 =  mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where product_no = '". $row['product_no'] ."' and category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat']) ."' or category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat1']) ."' or category like '". checkValue($_GET['cat2']) ."' ");

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        if($row2['sale'] == 'true'){
            $data[] = array("name"=>$row2['product_name'],"brand"=>$row2['product_brand'],"price"=>$row2['price'], "img_url"=>$row2['img'], "href"=>$row2['href'], "sale"=>$row2['sale'], "pre_price"=>$row2['pre_price'], "post_price"=>$row2['post_price'],  "percentage_discount"=>$row2['percentage_discount'] );
        }else{
            $data[] = array("name"=>$row2['product_name'],"brand"=>$row2['product_brand'],"price"=>$row2['price'], "img_url"=>$row2['img'], "href"=>$row2['href'], "sale"=>$row2['sale'], "pre_price"=>$row2['price'], "post_price"=>$row2['price'],  "percentage_discount"=>0);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @andy I have fixed two typos in my response. Let me know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Self join here to get your data for reference you can go with this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp).

example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1 T1, table1 T2
WHERE condition;
```